Mishnah Berurah's Torah Study Recommendation
Mishnah Berurah 155:3 says:

חייב אדם ללמוד בכל יום תורה שבכתב שהוא תנ"ך ומשנה וגמרא ופוסקים, a
person is obligated to learn every day [the] Written Torah, which
includes TaNaCH - Torah, Prophets and Writings - and Mishnah, and
Gemara and work of Halacha.

I went to a Jewish Orthodox elementary and high school. They were primarily dedicated to learning Gemara. Why aren't Jewish elementary and high schools dividing up their day learning TaNaCH, Mishnah, Gemara, and works of Halacha, as the Mishnah Berurah recommends?

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15139/why-isnt-tanach-regularly-studied-in-many-yeshivot, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61665/yeshivas-of-modern-times, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40916/why-do-yeshivos-learn-talmud-bavli-so-extensively

Those other subjects are included in Gemara

I do not have a written source for this one, but I believe that the reason is that the yeshivos for young students seek to provide their pupils with the tools that will enable a lifetime of "free-range" Torah study.  That means taking advantage of a limited time to give them the ability to learn and understand Gemara with its commentaries, and Shulchan Aruch with is commentaries, independently.  If they have the ability to do that by they time they leave yeshiva, they then have the ability to study any topic in Torah they wish.  If they lack that ability, they are crippled, likely for life.
The Mishnah Brurah, in contrast, is addressing himself to grown men who already have the ability to pursue their studies independently.  To them, he advises a balanced program of study, covering all the major areas of Torah learning.
