# Superfluous Rashi in Sukkah 52b?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, rashi, masechet-sukkah

[The Gemara](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=52b&format=pdf) proceeds to delineate the identities of the 7 shepherd and 8 princes mentioned in Michah 5:4. Amongst the 8 princes are עמוס and צפניה. Rashi ד״ה עמוס וצפניה states they are from Navi.

Is this not common knowledge, who else could have those names referred to?

Comment: Ashrei Chelkecha that the identities of the Trei Asar are common knowledge near you! May we all merit to have such be common knowledge everywhere, speedily in our days.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15139/759

Comment: Compare Rashbam on Bava Basra 111a sv kal

Answer (score 2):

Compare with the Rashi in proximity, which labels others as tzadikim. There are people who are included in these two lists, of shepherds and princes, for different reasons. Yishai, for instance, was a tzadik gamur. (See Shabbat 55b.)

Alternatively, it is seeking to explain why they are considered "princes". They are from among the prophets (rather than from books of Navi).