# Should one learn Navi daily, even if its in place of Gemara?

Tags: tanach

When learning Torah, it is very common to do the weekly Parsha, daf yomi, etc. However, I recently became interested in learning Neviim. This, of course, is not a generally daily-studied aspect of the Torah. Are there any sources that say that one should prioritize one over the other. Specifically, are there any sources that mention whether or not one should devote time to Nach (Neviim and Ketuvim), if they only had a specific amount of time set aside?

Comment: Everyone only has a specific amount of time set aside for learning.  For some people it might be 20 hours but it's still limited.

Comment: Yes; my question refers to whether Navi is a good use of that time.

Comment: So you're asking if anyone should ever learn Navi

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15140/759

Answer (score 3):

Here's one well-known source:

> "In light of this statement, the Sages said that a person should always divide his years into three parts, as follows: **A third for Bible<sup>1</sup>**, a third for Mishna, and a third for Talmud. The Gemara asks: How can a person divide his life this way? Who knows the length of his life, so that he can calculate how long a third will be? The Gemara answers: No, it is necessary for one’s days, i.e., one should divide each day of his life in this manner." ([Kiddushin 30a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kiddushin.30a.10?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi))

While this doesn't prioritize any of the three, it clearly states the importance of dividing one's time, however much time that is, between all three.

Also, the gemara in Avodah Zara 19a [says](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Avodah_Zarah.19a.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> "Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi says: A person can learn Torah only from a place in the Torah that his heart desires, as it is stated: But his delight is in the Torah of the Lord, i.e., his delight is in the part of the Torah that he wishes to study."

And the Mishnah Berura also [writes](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.553.8?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi&with=Shulchan%20Arukh,%20Orach%20Chayim&lang2=en):

> דאין אדם לומד אלא מה שלבו חפץ

Rough translation: A person should learn what their heart desires (i.e. is most interested in).

---

<sup>1</sup> The Hebrew word here is Mikra which refers to all three portions of the Tanach.

Comment: It is a gemara in Avoda Zara daf yud tes

Comment: @talmidforlife Thank you, I edited that in. It seems I didn't find it because it's not the exact same phrase.

Comment: My rough translation of the quoted Mishnah Berura would have been more like: That a person _only_ [truly] _learns_ what their heart desires (i.e. is most interested in). In other words, it's less advice, and more a statement about reality.