# Studying Chumash by myself

Tags: halacha, torah-study, chumash

Is it allowed to study Chumash with commentary (e.g. ArtScroll Chumash) by myself? Which aspects of Torah study are forbidden to do alone?

Comment: Why do you think learning alone is an issue?

Comment: "Aseh lekha rav", but if that's not possible, nothing wrong with studying alone from recognized sources.

Comment: Related and worth a read Shaine: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15140/31534

Comment: For sure Chumash isn't forbidden to learn by oneself, though one should make sure to learn Rashi and not just other commentaries - Rashi is the pashut peshat, the most basic explanation, and is necesary to understand what the Pasuk is saying.

Comment: It is a wonderful thing to do. Ideally you would have a rabbi or other knowledgeable friend available so that you can discuss your questions with. The Artscroll Stone chumash is an excellent compendium of commentaries to start with. I am not aware that learning alone is ever forbidden but the closer you get to the secrets of the Torah (e.g., Kabalah, Zohar), the harder and more risky it becomes to misunderstand.

Comment: Thanks, I'm indeed excited to study the commentaries in the Stone Edition, which I've glimpsed in shul during Torah reading, but wish for more time to delve into the insights. I've read the Chumash text in the past and have been an avid student of parsha shiurs and insight articles, but recently read a Talmud quote stating "scholars who sit alone to study the Torah...become foolish" (Berakhot 63b). Aware also of the chevrusa focus of Torah learning in yeshivas, I wanted to see if I need to find a study partner for this! Good to know that having Torah experts to consult is sufficient.

Comment: @ShaineLeah That quote is referring to someone who isolates themselves. Even in yeshivos where people have chavrusas, one still spends time learning on one's own. Especially chumash, where most people do not have partners.

Comment: You might also consider starting alone, then adding a chavruta as you decide to dig deeper. There are organizations such as Partners in Torah who can match you with someone ready to learn with you. In addition to whatever local options you might have

Comment: Thanks, Partners in Torah sounds great! I will definitely look into it.